# What is the max length for an external identifier of a model in odoo?

Tags: odoo, odoo-12

I would like to know what is the max length for an external identifier of a model in odoo?
It is possible that a id too long could cause an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The external identifier is stored in [complete_name](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/12.0/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_model.py#L1350) char field which has no size limit.

A [char](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/12.0/odoo/fields.py#L1456) field is represented with a character varying in Postgresql.

From Odoo [source code](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/d55694e95fe9d7c5c27995b65de86107ab133ac5/odoo/tools/sql.py#L219) documentation:

> > If no size (or an empty or negative size is provided) return an
> >           'infinite' VARCHAR

Referring to Postgresql [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/datatype-character.html#DATATYPE-CHARACTER-TABLE):

> > If character varying is used without length specifier, the type accepts strings of any size.

*Using `ref` with an external identifier up to 2500 characters in length works fine*.